# Как сделать выборку каскадом DB в Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel

как сделать выборку каскадом DB подобно такой SELECT id1, number,(SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE id2=id1) FROM table1

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нравится мне такой запрос, но он должен работать:

```
$row = \DB::table('table1')
          ->select('id as id1','name',DB::raw('(SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE id2=id1) as value'))
          ->get();
```